# Сайт, на котором компилируется код, выдаёт ошибку "Программа завершила работу с ненулевым кодом возврата"

Tags: python

Задача:

> Даны два числа A и B. Вам нужно вычислить их сумму A+B. В этой задаче
> вам нужно читать из файла и выводить ответ в файл Первая строка
> входного файла содержит числа A и B (-2 ⋅ 109 ≤ A, B ≤ 2 ⋅ 109)
> разделенные пробелом В единственной строке выходного файла выведите
> сумму чисел A+B

При отправке на проверку выдаётся ошибка "Программа завершила работу с ненулевым кодом возврата".

Вот мой код:

```
inp = input()
f = open(inp, 'r')
f = f.read()
a = f.split()
print(a)
a = int(a[0])+ int(a[1])
out = open('output.txt', 'w')
out.write(str(a))
out.close()
```

Что можно сделать?

Comment: Лучше открывайте файлы через `with`, чтобы не приходилось их закрывать. Вы тут теряете хэндл входного файла и не закрываете его. Хотя это в общем не большой криминал.

Comment: А вы уверены что название входного файла нужно брать из инпута?

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что адресовать его следует автору проверяющей системы

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as inp:
    answer = inp.read()
with open("output.txt", "w") as out:
    answer = answer.split()
    out.write(str(int(answer[0])+int(answer[1])))
```

Не самое оптимальное решение, но работает как надо.
Спасибо всем, кто отвечал)